# Taylor series, but alternating sign every two, not every one

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Formulate an exponent $u$ for $(-1)^u$ that fits the following pattern.  In the alternative, propose any other **polynomial expression** to substitute for $(-1)^u$ that satisfies the pattern.

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^u\;\; a_n = a_0 - a_1 -a_2 + a_3 + a_4 -a_5 - a_6 + a_7 + a_8...$$

My book proposed a solution that required sine as part of the expansion of sine.  That's a tautology, defining a function in terms of itself. As far as I understand, neither modulo nor trigonometric functions are part of polynomials.

[Edited] Theo Bendit's response below is great. Thanks

Comment: $(-1)^{\lfloor \frac12 (u+1)\rfloor}$

Comment: Not that I like to court such things, but the typical response to receiving a satisfactory answer to your query is to press the big green tick, rather than edit your acceptance into your question!

Answer (score 2):

The triangular numbers $\frac{1}{2}n(n + 1)$ alternate parity like this:
$$0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, \ldots$$
So,
$$(-1)^{n(n + 1) / 2}$$
would presumably fit the brief of a "polynomial expression" (though, the expression is not polynomial, it is $-1$ to the power of a polynomial of $n$; there is no polynomial of $n$ that could produce this sequence of $1$s and $-1$s).

Answer (score 0):

$$a_k=\frac{(1+i)i^k+(1-i)(-i)^k}2$$
looks promising.